# How can i make the whole project to run in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using intelliJ IDEA for a project in which i declare 4 different classes in separate files namely as A,B,C,D and uses inheritance.

Class D contains main method,On running D it runs properly. But when i try to run the whole project it shows the error as shown in image.

[image]

What can i do to make this project working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using incorrect Run/Debug configuration. [Create a new one](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) using the [Application type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html).

It's also not clear what you mean by "try to run the whole project". You run Java application using an entry point, a class with the `main` method. So, what's the difference between running the `D` class `main` method and running the whole project?

Comment: Precisely. There is nothing called "run project" in Java. You can add a static main method in every class and enter the "project" from any of them.

Comment: Running whole project means running all features in project.

Comment: @ShubhamRai There is no "features" concept in a plain Java project. You are trying to run [Cucumber features](https://www.guru99.com/cucumber-basics.html) run configuration which is completely unrelated.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I edit the Configuration and set main class as D by removing Cucumber but it keep showing me the same error

Comment: @ShubhamRai delete the Cucumber configuration entirely, right click in D class and Run it from the context menu instead or create the Application configuration manually.